# How to configure distinct distributionManagement repositories to plugins and libs?

Tags: java, maven, deployment, artifactory

I'm trying to configure the distributionManagement section of a parent POM to enable the upload of libs and plugins to distinct Artifactory repositories, but maven 3 only supports one section of distributionManagement configuration.

As I use differente repositories to download plugins and libs and it's not usable to create one parent POM to each type of artifact, is it possible to configure distinct repositories to let Artifactory, or simply maven, identify the type of artifact and deploy to the correct repository?

Here is this current pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ornanization</groupId>
    <artifactId>corporative-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>artifactoryRelease</id>
            <name>artifactory-libs-releases<name>
            <url>${artifactory.url}/libs-release-local</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>artifactorySnapshot</id>
            <name>artifactory-libs-snapshots</name>
            <url>${artifactory.url}/libs-snapshot-local</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

And this is the entry I'd like to add:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>artifactoryRelease</id>
        <name>artifactory-plugins-releases</name>
        <url>${artifactory.url}/plugins-release-local</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>artifactorySnapshot</id>
        <name>artifactory-plugins-snapshots</name>
        <url>${artifactory.url}/plugins-snapshot-local</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

p.s.: as stated on [this page](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+with+Maven#WorkingwithMaven-SettingUpDistributionManagement) of the Artifactory's User Guide, it's not possible to "deploy build artifacts to remote or virtual repositories" only to local repositories, so it's not possible to let Artifactory's layout management identify the artifact's type.

Comment: For downloading your settings.xml is the right location where you define where to download artifacts whereas distributionManagement is used to upload artifacts. Apart from that make a distinction between plugins and libs does not really make sense...

Comment: Actually, as we are in a corporate environment, we have tried to let the local configuration file as small as possible so, despite the best practices, we'll need to keep the repositories configuration on the a Super POM. 
But I agree with the unecessary distinction between the repositories. I'll try to argue with the responsible for the Artifactory server to change this layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @JBaruch tip to "define a variable that will represent plugin and lib repositories", I first did a research on maven profiles to activate from a variable and realize that it's possible to activate a profile if a certain condition is matched, so I ended up with the following solution:

```
<profile>
    <id>plugins-deploy-artifactory</id>
    <activation>
        <file>
            <exists>target/classes/META-INF/maven/plugin.xml</exists>
        </file>
    </activation>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>artifactoryRelease</id>
            <name>artifactory-corporativo-releases</name>
            <url>${artifactory.url}/plugins-release-local</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>artifactorySnapshot</id>
            <name>artifactory-corporativo-snapshots</name>
            <url>${artifactory.url}/plugins-snapshot-local</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</profile>
```

So when the artifact is a plugin, the profile above is activated, otherwise, the default distributionManagement is used.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't use the `<distributionManagement>` and use the [Artifactory Maven Plugin](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Maven+Artifactory+Plugin) instead.

The `<repoKey>` tag of the configuration allows you to use variables (both environment and project defined). Just define a variable that will represent plugin and lib repositories and set the values in the corresponding projects.

Also, you'll get the full [Build Info BOM](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration) on deployment as a bonus.

Comment: I prefered the solution using profiles because it kept the integration with the repository server less coupled. Since we still desire the repository shift to Nexus, it'll take less changes to adaptation. But thanks for the variables conditional usage tip, it led me to solution.

Comment: The most important gain of using the Artifactory plugin is the build integration. Did you take a look on what you are going to miss?
http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration

Comment: BTW, may I also ask you why you plan to move to Nexus?

Comment: Too bad the maven plugin works only with Artifactory Pro :(